# How to send large var Data from javascript to SpringMVC Controller?

Tags: javascript, spring, hibernate

I am working in springMVC .I am facing one Problem my javascript function has large Text Value in the form of json i want to send the data from javascript to my controller How can i do this any one help me
  Please check my code

```
  function jsonString()
 {
   var jsonData ="{ description: "GM, DML Server Marketing",
                        email: "jeankend@name.com",
                        groupTitleColor: "#4169e1",
                        image: "d.png",
                        itemTitleColor: "#4b0082",
                        phone: "949-453-0415",
                        title: "Jean Kendall"
                    },
                    { description: "GM, Application Platform and Development Marketing",
                        email: "bradwhit@name.com",
                        groupTitleColor: "#4169e1",
                        image: "f.png",
                        itemTitleColor: "#4b0082",
                        phone: "502-528-6379",
                        title: "Brad Whitt"
                    }
 }"
```

like i have large data is there..Now i want to store this json format data in my database by using spring mvc how can i send this data from javascript to my controller in spring mvc 
I Follwed this way please Check my code
 In my controller

```
        public  @ResponseBody String saveOrgChart(@PathVariable String domainName,@RequestParam String domainId,@RequestBody String  jsonStr)
      {
    logger.warning("the domainName is..:"+domainName);
    logger.warning("the domainId is....:"+domainId);
    logger.warning("the jsonStirng is.."+jsonStr);
    Long primaryDomainId = 0L;
    }
```

is it correct or any another way is there? please tell me

Answer (score 0):

Don't use Strings... You live in an Object world, use Objects. Create an object which can hold your data and instead of a plain string send it as an Array of JSON object. An array can be retrieved as a list/collection of elements.

```
public class Person {
    private String description;
    private String email;
    private String groupTitleColor;
    private String image;
    private String itemTitleColor;
    private String phone;
    private String title;

    // Getters/Setters omitted
}
```

Now your controller can look like the following

public  @ResponseBody String saveOrgChart(@PathVariable String domainName,@RequestParam String domainId,@RequestBody List persons) { ... }

Although it could be that you need to wrap the List in another container object.

Comment: Hi thanks for the replay but for me the json data generated in my javascript function

Comment: So... What has your clientside stuff to do with the sever-side representation. As long as it can be unmarshalled there is no problem.